# Weather API implementation

Tags: c#, api

This class uses the openweathermap API to receive information about the current weather and forecasts. I am looking for any type of advice, but primary for structure and style improvement suggestions:
This method builds the the API URL:

```
private Uri BuildQueryURL(Interval requestType, NameValueCollection parameters)
{
    if (parameters == null) parameters = new NameValueCollection();
    string relativePath = "";
    //set query//
    switch (requestType)
    {
        case Interval.Current:
            relativePath = "weather";
            break;
        case Interval.Forecast:
            relativePath = "forecast";
            break;
    }
    //add api key//
    parameters.Add("APPID", ApiKey);
    //if needed, add unit parameter//
    if (Units != Units.Default) parameters.Add("units", Units.ToString());
    //build uri
    var builder = new UriBuilder();
    builder.Scheme = "http://";
    builder.Host = "api.openweathermap.org";
    builder.Path = Path.Combine("data/2.5", relativePath);
    builder.Query = string.Join("&", parameters.AllKeys.Select((name) => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameters[name]))));
    return builder.Uri;
}
```

The actual query is done by following method:

```
private RequestStatus Execute(Uri queryURI, out string queryResponse)
    {
        queryResponse = null;
        var status = RequestStatus.OK;
        try
        {
            queryResponse = _client.DownloadString (queryURI);
            //this methods parses the code parameter of the query response//
            status = CheckResponseCode(queryResponse);
        }
        catch(WebException) {
            status = RequestStatus.Failed;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Here is the deserialization of the received data:

```
 private CurrentWeather DeserializeCurrentWeather(string queryResponse)
    {
        var currentWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentWeather>(queryResponse);
        currentWeather.Units = this.Units;
        currentWeather.Country = CountryCodeHelper.ConvertToName((string)JObject.Parse(queryResponse).SelectToken("sys.country"));
        return currentWeather;
    }
```

This is called by the consumer:

```
public RequestStatus GetWeatherByZip(int zip, string countryCode, out CurrentWeather result)
    {
        return GetWeather(new NameValueCollection() { { "zip", CombineQueryCountryCode(zip.ToString(), countryCode) } }, out result);
    }
public RequestStatus GetWeatherByCity(string city, string countryCode, out CurrentWeather result)
    {
        return GetWeather(new NameValueCollection() { { "q", CombineQueryCountryCode(city,countryCode) } }, out result);
    }
//...//
private RequestStatus GetWeather(NameValueCollection parameters, out CurrentWeather result)
    {
        string queryResponse;
        RequestStatus status = RequestStatus.OK;
        status = Execute(BuildQueryURL(Interval.Current, parameters), out queryResponse);
        result = DeserializeCurrentWeather(queryResponse);
        return status;
    }
```

I excluded the async methods and forecast methods. The complete source can be found at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/R3turnz/OpenWeather).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BuildQueryURL** method

This method is in a very bad style. It's supposed to build a query url but you give it a name-value-collection that you modify it inside the method!

You should split it into two methods.

The first one should only `UpdateParameters` and the other one `BuildQueryURL` only build the url without modifying any other values and causing unexpected behaviour. I'd be really supprised if I used it and found that it actually changed the parameters too although it's name doesn't suggest anything like that.

---

**Interval** enum

If this is your enum then make the values exactly like the relative path so that you can just call `.ToString()` on it without a switch. If not then I'd use a dictionary to get rid of the switch.

---

**Execute & GetWeather** methods

Usually when we do somehting like this where we have an `out` argument and return a `bool` or another type of a result success indicator we name the method `TryDoSomething` so in your case the method should be called `TryExecuteQuery` and `TryGetWeather`